# Problem sending a JSON string to an API requiring an array of objects

Tags: php, json, data-transfer

I have got some data in PHP that I want to send to an API writen in JSON format.
 My data was a PHP array whereby I convert to a JSON object then to a JSON string so that I can send. But the API requires an array of objects as shown in the code below,, how can i write my code to fit its format

**Requirements from the array writen in JSON format**

```
{
"children":[
    {"child_name":"abc","child_dob":"2015-05-23"},
    {"child_name":"efg","child_dob":"2016-09-13"}
  ]
}
```

**My PHP code**

```
//Convert the PHP array to a JSON object
    $child =(object)$children;

    //Convert JSON object to a JSON string to send to server
    $ch = json_encode($child);

    dd($ch);

    //result in browser
   "{"child_name":"mnmbmb","child_dob":"2018-10-30"}"
```

Comment: Please show us your php array `$children`

Comment: "I convert to a JSON object then to a JSON string"...this make no sense. JSON is just a string. It's _decodable_ into objects etc, but as soon as you make it into JSON, you already have a string. When you commented `//Convert the PHP array to a JSON object` you're actually still turning it into a PHP object. It's not JSON until you encode it as a JSON string. You might think I'm nitpicking but it helps to use the right terminology, then everyone is clear about what you mean, and can be sure that you understand what you're doing.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks,, duly noted

Comment: @HarveyFletcher This my my children array `['child_name' => $childname , 'child_dob' => $childdob]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need to convert it to object. Try this instead

```
$data=array();
$data['children'] =$children;
//Convert JSON object to a JSON string to send to server
$ch = json_encode($data);

dd($ch);
```

Comment: Hi,, I have implemented your solution and I get the following data after dd() `"{"children":{"child_name":"mnmbmb","child_dob":"2018-10-30"}}"` This is still throwing error with the API which expects children property to contain an array of objects as shown below `"children":[
    {"child_name":"abc","child_dob":"2015-05-23"},
    {"child_name":"efg","child_dob":"2016-09-13"}
  ]` format

Comment: Your `$children` array as you have shown above contains only one row but it should contain an array of values or rows.

Comment: I have checked the documentation and it can accept 1 row,, the data am sending is a JSON string, how do I convert it back to a JSON object which is the format that the API requires

Comment: By array of values or rows I meant that your `$children` array must be a 2d array. For example try using this array as `$children`:
`array(array('child_name'=>'abc','child_dob'=>'2015-05-23'),array('child_name'=>'efg','child_dob'=>'2016-09-13'))`